# How do I conduct an upgrade from Magento v1.4.1.1 to 1.7.0.2?

Tags: upgrade

How do I conduct an upgrade from Magento v1.4.1.1 to 1.7.0.2 ?

Hello !

I'm thinking of upgrading Magento v1.4.1.1 to v1.7.0.2
I have never conducted this kind of operation.
I have read there are two ways of doing it. Using SSH or Magento Back-Office.
I know I can't upgrade directly from v1.4.1.1 to v1.7.0.2. 
I might need to pass by v1.4.2.0, v1.5.1.0 and v1.6.2.0
I have read loads of forums articles. None of them explains the 
process the same way.

What way is the best to conduct this operation (SSH or by Back-Office) ?
How to conduct this operation via SSH ?
How to conduct this operation via Back-Office ?
How do I specify the name of the new version I want to install, from magento Back-Office (and from SSH) ?
How do customers and admin data bases get updated after core and skin files ?

[image]

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: best option which works for me all the time, clean DB log tables, replace old magento files with new files ( keep local.xml and media folder)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! What do you mean by cleaning DB log tables ? Cleaning cache from /var/www/var/cache ? Cleaning session from /var/www/var/session ?  How do you get back all your customers DB informations ?

Comment: nothing to do with customers saved in DB, to clean your log please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638361/clearing-magento-log-data

Comment: How do customers and admin DB get updated after DB cleaning ?

Comment: DB Cleaning will not change anything related to customers or admin you are only cleaning the log table to make the upgrade a bit faster.

Comment: So how do I get back all my old customers DB without troubles on the new magento ?

Answer (score 1):

First: You should not do this with Magento Connect, nor would I ever recommend using Magento connect [for anything].

According to Magento You **DO NOT** have to do an incremental upgrade.

You will need to test and apply the new XML updates on your theme.

There is alot of work involved in this upgrade and there are many steps that have to happen and you need to check each aspect of the upgrade. I would recommend having your Magento Solution Integrator handle your upgrade.

If you read through the WIKI on the Magento site you will find the step-by-step guide in doing your upgrade. Your customers and all your data will follow in the upgrade.

**Read the WIKI on upgrades**
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/manual_upgrade_using_fresh_install_and_original_database